# How can I send push notifications by MS Teams custom app?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams

I have a custom MS Teams app (made with React as Front-End and C# as Back-End) and I would like my app to send a notification when an event occurs, for example:

- A user reserves a seat in a restaurant for a certain day at 20.30

I want my app to send a notification that same day 1 hour before the event. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the notification in Teams using below ways:

- Incoming webhook
- Activity feed notification

Ref Documents:

[Create an Incoming Webhook - Teams | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is pretty much what I want to do, except that I don't think that you can schedule notifications, I'll find a workaround